# Como mostrar un mensaje abajo de un elemento que tiene display flex

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo un Login, que es más complejo que lo que acabo de postear, pero en realidad lo que puse es mi problema. Estoy validando si los campos no vienen vacíos, si viene vacío agregar entonces un mensaje de error justo debajo del input que se validó. En el password funciona bien pero en el correo me lo pone a lado, esto por que el div que los contiene tiene un `display:flex-inline;`

¿Qué puedo hacer para bajar ese mensaje?

PD: No me gustaría moverle tanto por que ya tengo varias cosas que funcionan así, pero si no hay solución más viable pues ni modo.

Saludos

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '#login', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //Primero borro los mensajes de error
    $('.regex_error').each(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });

    //Asignamos variables a selectores
    var user = $('#user'),
      pass = $('#pass');
    //Limpiamos los bordes
    user.css('border-color', '#ccc');
    pass.css('border-color', '#ccc');

    //Validamos si el selector esta vacio
    if (user.val() == '') {
      //Cambiamos el borde de color
      user.css('border-color', '#ff8080');
      //Agregamos un mensaje, pero al div que contiene el selector (Es decir en el mismo div pero otro nodo)
      user.parent().append('<p class="regex_error">Este campo no puede ir vacío</p>');
    }

    if (pass.val() == '') {
      pass.css('border-color', '#ff8080');
      pass.parent().append('<p class="regex_error">Este campo no puede ir vacío</p>');
    }
  });

})
```

```css
.regex_error {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  color: #ff8080;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="text-secondary" for="user">Usuario</label>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
    <input
      type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm collector"
      data-key="user" data-regex="0" data-req="1"
      id="user" placeholder="Escribe tu usuario del correo electrónico">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text">@example.com</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="text-secondary" for="pass">Contraseña</label>
  <input
    type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm collector"
    data-key="pass" id="pass" data-regex="password" data-req="1"
    max-maxlength="15" placeholder="Escribe tu contraseña" id="pass">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary" id="login">Ingresar</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta usando `.after` en vez de `.append`:

```js
$(function(){

    $(document).on('click','#login',function( e ){
      e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
      //Primero borro los mensajes de error
   $('.regex_error').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });
      
      //Asignamos variables a selectores
      var user = $('#user'),
          pass = $('#pass');
      //Limpiamos los bordes
      user.css('border-color', '#ccc');
      pass.css('border-color', '#ccc');
      
      //Validamos si el selector esta vacio
      if( user.val() == '' ){
        //Cambiamos el borde de color
        user.css('border-color', '#ff8080');
        //Agregamos un mensaje, pero al div que contiene el selector (Es decir en el mismo div pero otro nodo)
        user.parent().after('<p class="regex_error">Este campo no puede ir vacío</p>');
      }
      
      if( pass.val() == '' ){
        pass.css('border-color', '#ff8080');
        pass.parent().append('<p class="regex_error">Este campo no puede ir vacío</p>');
      }
  });

})
```

```css
.regex_error{
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  color:#ff8080;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="text-secondary" for="user">Usuario</label>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm collector"
       data-key="user" data-regex="0" data-req="1"
            id="user" placeholder="Escribe tu usuario del correo electrónico">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">@example.com</span>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="text-secondary" for="pass">Contraseña</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm collector"
          data-key="pass" id="pass" data-regex="password" data-req="1" max-maxlength="15"
          placeholder="Escribe tu contraseña" id="pass">
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary" id="login">Ingresar</button>
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda.